# Compare two array-containing lists in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have two lists in Python each one containing an array. e.g

```
list1[0]
out: array([[ 1, 2, 3],[ 4, 5, 6], . . .]], dtype=float32)

list2[0]
out: array([[ 1, 5, 3],[ 4, 5, 6], . . .]], dtype=float32)    

and list1[0][0]
out: array([ 1, 2, 3], dtype=float32)

and list2[0][0]
out: array([ 1, 5, 3], dtype=float32)
```

The lists contain points that represent lines in the 3d space.
I want to check if these two lists are identical i.e if they represent the same lines in the 3d space. I have tried all(), any(), set() etc. but these functions work on non-array containing lists. Any ideas?

Comment: what are your two lists that you want to compare?

Comment: You wrote "I want to check if these two lists are identical". What are those two lists? You only posted one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After comparing the length of both lists you can iterate and use NumPy's `array_equal` function:

```
using numpy as np

def listsEqual(list1, list2):
    return len(list1) == len(list2) and np.all([np.array_equal(l1, l2) for l1, l2 in zip(list1, list2)])
```

Answer (score 0):

First check that the arrays have the same shape, and then reshape and check if they are identical -

```
list1.shape == list2.shape and np.array_equal(list1.reshape(-1,), list2.reshape(-1,))
```

or

```
list1.shape == list2.shape and np.all(list1.reshape(-1,) == list2.reshape(-1,))
```